# WordPress - Avada theme disable boxed mode on mobile screens

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a question about a project with WordPress and the Avada theme. There is a boxed mode option with a dropshadow customization. But when we use the website on mobile, it's not friendly. I would like to disable it!

I think I have to use media queries with CSS properties, but I don't know how...

You can find the project with this link: https://lr-architectes.com

I have already tried something like that in WordPress CSS customizer

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .body .html {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .layout-boxed-mode {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

No results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an error in your CSS syntax. You're missing some vital keywords in your code:

```css
// the keywords `screen` and `and` were missing
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .body .html {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .layout-boxed-mode {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

To learn more about CSS media queries refer to W3Schools's docs on it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)